# Cant assign a material to landscape properly

Tags: materials

I hope I can get help because I am stuck since yesterday.

I cant apply materials to landscapes (the ones Blender creates for you in one klick). If I add a primitive and try the same material, it works fine, as you can see in my screenshot below.
The only thing that changes on the landscape is the color. If I go to the shader mode, the nodes of the material are exactly the same as on the primitive. So it is applied, but I dont get it work.

I tried to subdivide the mesh because this has been the problem once, but it did not work here.

I have no idea why this is happening.

I work in Blender 3.0 and toughed nothing else in this blender file, then creating a landscape, a sphere and added the same material from my library.

Looks the same in cycles.

I am sorry for this (obviously) Noob-question. I searched the forum, I searched on google, but was not able to find something. Maybe I searched wrong?

Thank you very much for the help!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPhsP.jpg

Comment: Is your terrain object UV unwrapped ?

Comment: Good question, I just assumed those Blender created landscapes are, like primitives. How do I make sure?

Comment: Found it! It wasnt! You made my day, be blessed my friend! Thank you so much!